# EJS dynamic include

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to dynamicly include one of my partials, using EJS. I render a template like so:

Router

```
router.get('/', noteController.getNotes, (req, res, next) => {
    return res.render(template, {'page':'all'})
})
```

And am trying to include a partial in this template, based on the variable "page".

template.ejs

```
<% include %><%= page %><% .ejs %>
```

This however does not work. I have tried multiple methods, to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply:

```
<%- include(page) %>
```

or if it's in `partials` folder:

```
<%- include('partials/'+page) %>
```

P.S. don't forget to declare view engine to be `ejs`:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

From [official source](http://ejs.co/#docs) :

> <%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template
>
> You'll likely want to use the raw output tag (<%-) with your include
> to avoid double-escaping the HTML output.

Comment: When I try this I recieve an error: "esc is not a function"

Comment: @n0rd also I think in Your partial file `all` there is `<%=` statement that tries to print some variable that does not exist (is `undefined`) so when You print with escaping `<%=` it tries to call `.esc` on that variable.

Comment: @n0rd also please put `all.ejs` in Your question also

Comment: I simplified my orginal code for my question. I will update my question with all the code and errors. Just a moment.

Comment: Well. After going through my code again. It ended up working with: <%- include('parts/'+page+'.ejs') %> I think it was just because I was missing the 'parts/' which is the folder I keep my parts. Thanks!

Comment: @n0rd congrats (:

Comment: <%= include(page) %>  renders the raw html on the page (for me at least) <%- include(page) %> renders an error

Comment: @richardwhitney are You sure that You've properly passed `page` variable to view? Also can You put in comments the error that You get? Might be ejs has issues depending on version.

Comment: turns out I had a space between include and (file) like this: include (file) - this rendered an error - it needed to be <%- include(file) %>.  coming from a PHP background, this was not obvious to me at first.

Comment: @richardwhitney both: `<%- include(file) %>` and `<% include file %>` works. difference is that with `<%- include(file, {users: [array of user], something: 'else'}) %>`  You can pass local variables to included file, when other one just includes file like: `<% inlcude partials/footer %>` .  Seems like when You've put whitespace it tried to load file: `(file).ejs`

Comment: @num8er I will have to try <%- include(file, {users: [array of user], something: 'else'}) %> - hadn't thought of that.  I was just passing a dynamic filename, not vars too

Answer (score 2):

for example using for Login page

```
app.get('/login', (req, res)=>{
  res.render('layout', {page: 'login'})
})
```

here is simple layout.ejs

```
<body>
    <% include ./templates/nav %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <% include ./templates/leftbar %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <%- include(page) %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <% include ./templates/rightbar %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% include ./templates/footer %>
</body>
```

login.ejs

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Password:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```